# Change only status bar's color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I have a layout like this and I want to change the color of only the status bar as I have not used an Appbar.

[image: Layout]

Here's the code I have used for this:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextFormField(
                cursorColor: Colors.green,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                  hintText: 'Search a product',
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  prefixIcon: Visibility(
                    visible: true,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200, width: 1.5
                    )
                  ),
                )
              ),
            ),

            //AND OTHER ELEMENTS

        ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to change the color of the status bar to a darker shade of green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our `main.dart`, we can use the `SystemChrome` class:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.green
));
```

Comment: Actually I added this inside `build` in Home Widget and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AppBar(
  backwardsCompatibility: false,
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.orange),
)
```

Comment: This creates an Appbar at the top which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

You can give it in MaterialApp bar theme of Directly inside your appbar

**In Material app global theme**

```
MaterialApp(
        
          theme: ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              brightness: Brightness.dark,

              backwardsCompatibility: false,
              systemOverlayStyle:
                  SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.orange),
)
```

`statusBarColor` is the color of topBar that you want to change.
It's important to set `backwardsCompatibility: false` because it will not work.

Comment: I just want to change the color of the statusbar. I don't want to add an extra appbar. Your code adds an appbar below the status bar. Thank you

Comment: only add the appbar theme on Material then you will be able to change the color of statusbar without adding appbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
```

)